# Could theoretically ID of tweet be equal to ID of direct message?

Tags: twitter

In my application I can successfully read and send both tweets and direct messages and I can also read their respective IDs.

Could it in theory ever happen that a single ID of some tweet would be equal to ID of some direct message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Twitter's [Snowflake](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/06/announcing-snowflake.html) means all IDs are unique.  So there will never be a collision between DM and Tweet IDs.